# How do I get index of first matching element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, match

WIth Ruby 2.4, I want to detect the first index of a matching element in my array.  But I'm discovering "detect_with_index" is not a function in Ruby ...

```
2.4.0 :005 > distance = "two"
...
2.4.0 :008 >     NUMBERS_IN_WORDS_TOKENS = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
 => ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
2.4.0 :009 >   distance = NUMBERS_IN_WORDS_TOKENS.detect_with_index{|str, index| str.eql?(distance.downcase) ? index : nil}
NoMethodError: undefined method `detect_with_index' for #<Array:0x007fe69b2692b8>
Did you mean?  each_with_index
    from (irb):9
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How do I find the first matching index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [Array.index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index), aka [find_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index), like

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.index("b")              #=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this:

```
match = list.find { |l| l.owner == myself }
match_index = list.index(match)
```

Comment: index takes a block: `match_index = list.index{ |l| l.owner == myself }`

Answer (score 0):

```
NUMBERS_IN_WORDS_TOKENS.find_index(distance)
```

Please find explaination [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/find_index) it returns first index.